# Need a reusable SelectAll ViewModel

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have often run into situations where I want to have a 3-State checkbox to select all/deselect all of my view models.  I have run into difficulties creating a reusable class to do this with.

I tried to create the following base classes:

```
public class SelectAllListVM
{
   public List<SelectableVM> ChildList = new List<SelectableVM>();
   public bool? SelectAll   // call UpdateSelectedChildren on set 

   internal void UpdateSelectAll ()   
      // Set SelectAll based on ChildList elements
      // true = all selected,  false = non selected, null = some selected


   private void UpdateSelectedChildren ()   {
      foreach ( SelectableVM vm in ChildList )
         vm.SetIsSelected( SelectAll.Value );
   }
}

public class SelectableVM
{
   public SelectableVM (SelectAllListVM parentVM) {}
   public bool IsSelected    // call parentVM.UpdateSelectAll 
}
```

The problem with this is every time I want to iterate through the ChildList I have to cast the SelectableVM to it's concrete implementation.  How can I reuse this behavior and avoid casting?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an Interface ISelectableVM

```
public interface ISelectableVM
{
   public bool IsSelected;
}
```

and implement it in your derived classes.

```
public class SelectableVM : ISelectableVM
{}

public class OtherSelectableVM : ISelectableVM
{}
```

Then in your ParentVM you don't have to cast:

```
public class SelectAllListVM
{
   public List<ISelectableVM> ChildList = new List<ISelectableVM>();
   public bool? SelectAll; // call UpdateSelectedChildren on set 

   private void UpdateSelectedChildren()
   {
      foreach (ISelectableVM vm in ChildList)
         vm.IsSelected = SelectAll.Value;
   }
}
```

Instead of an `interface` you could also use

```
public class BaseSelectableVM
{
   public bool IsSelected;
}
```

and derive from it.

Comment: I don't think this will work for me.  I'm trying to avoid explicit casts to my derived class when accessing the child list.

Comment: I have added example code. There is no need to cast to your derived class.

Comment: Indeed, if you use `foreach (ISelectableVM in ChildList.OfType<ISelectableVM>())` you can even have your list include things that don't implement `ISelectableVM`.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it. Let's say OtherSelectableVM has a Data property and then I want to do this:  var selquery = from vm in myParentVM.ChildList where vm.IsSelected select vm.Data;

Comment: If only OtherSelectableVM has this Data property you have to cast anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I did some attached behavior trickery back in the day to do this. Everything is handled by the view no need for the VM to care about select all logic. I wrote the details of how to do it in three parts ([part 1](http://kharasoft.wordpress.com/2007/05/08/attached-properties-markup-extensions-and-multibindings-oh-my/), [part 2](http://kharasoft.wordpress.com/2007/05/08/previously-on-brownie-points/), [part 3](http://kharasoft.wordpress.com/2007/05/09/season-finale/)) I made the code available on fileden...and subsequently lost it because I didn't log into the account enough times. But all the code is there throughout the three posts.

Comment: Interesting, I think this does everything I want to do. However I get an annoying bogus error in the VS designer as outlined here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/369812/multiple-constructor-for-a-markupextension-breaks-the-wpf-designer which may be a deal breaker for me.  Issues in connect.microsoft seem to get escalated and never heard from again.

Comment: I must admit, I've never used this since the time I originally wrote it. Let me fire it up and see what can be done. Glad you like the idea though.